# 500 (Service unavailable (with message)) on login or register

Tags: users, debugging, authentication-authorization

Effectively the same as this ([Drupal 500 Internal server error on login page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145852/drupal-500-internal-server-error-on-login-page)) but i am unable to bump or comment so resorting to adding my own question.

The site is running Drupal 7.54 php version 7 and uses LoginToboggan module with login.

I am receiving "500 (Service unavailable (with message))" on the user and register pages, this occurs against user/login and ?q=user/login equivalent. Otherwise the site operates normally. There are no PHP errors in the log or browser console so i have nothing to try and trace.

I have amended the .htaccess file to use Rewrite as suggested elsewhere (this was already enabled anyway as the site sits in a subdomain).

Clean URLs are enabled.

I have added error reporting to settings.php to try and pick up on errors i've otherwise missed, nada.

I have used phpMyAdmin to clear the sessions table as suggested on another old thread. This resulted in me being kicked out and unable to get back in.

I can now only access the site db via phpMyAdmin and the site files via ftp (unable to log in as admin as login throws the error)

I tried to run update.php (removing login requirement from settings) out of sheer desperation but this had no effect.

Again in desperation i removed the LoginToboggan module (via ftp, i know) to try and revert the login to core but this had no effect.

I thought the main domain was conflicting in some way so i removed it (it wasn't actually used for anything and had an independent db so i just uninstalled it. No effect.

I really am at a loss, i can't figure out the cause and so have no way to implement a fix..

Comment: Hard to give an answer to your problem without some kind of log, but. To disable a module from the DB, you set the `status` to `0` in the `system` table. A list of handy commands: https://www.drupal.org/node/157632 . Additionally, you can login, enable, disable etc. using Drush. Login is `drush uli` (that will be user 1) and uninstall would be `drush pmu module_name`, see: https://drushcommands.com

Comment: The command list is useful thank you. I have now disabled LoginToboggan though no change. If you could suggest where else i might find an explicit error i'll take a look but i really am at a loss.

Comment: I assume you have dblog turned on? Then you should get watchdog errors in reports. It's called `Recent log messages` at `/admin/reports/dblog`. Other than that, I can't think of anything just now… Is this on your local or online?

Comment: I can't access the reports page but i thought i had.. The site is online. I should have added it had been (more or less) working fine for some-time.

Comment: If you still can't login (I'm assuming you don't have Drush) you can see the reports in the DB, suddenly not sure what the table is called, but I think it's in the `watchdog` table. I would recommend you spin up a local copy and use Drush.

Comment: Going to take me a little time but thanks for the support and suggestions. You're right i need a local copy to work on i think that has to be the next step.

Comment: per mediaashley's suggestion i checked the watchdog in db. While most of it was jibberish to me it mentioned an custom module we use. I have no idea why this module should be interfering with user login and registration but deactivating it resolved this problem. If you add an answer to this effect i'll mark and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have access to the database through PhpMyAdmin, have a look in the `watchdog` table for any errors.

Disable anything causing an issue ;)